# Managing outages to make ArcSDE updates?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, enterprise-geodatabase, data-management

I would like options to manage ArcSDE outages for making updates to schema, which I am not able to do when users are just reading the feature classes.  I would like to not have to stay late to get these changes and I would like to not have downtime for an hour.  I imagine well thought design would mitigate this.

I need to delete a few objects and create a few objects.

Comment: Is this question substantially different from your [previous one](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27130/sde-analysis-file-locking-logistics-arcsde-10-on-mssql)?